# Sudoku solver in c crashes

Tags: c, sudoku

I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my code which is supposed to solve a 9x9 sudoku which crashes when I run it with the example in the Wikipedia for sudoku.

I have also tried using recursion but am not very familiar with it so it did not work either.

- `findunassignedlocation` returns `1` if there are still 0s in the sudoku and `0` if there are no more 0s.
- `isSafe` returns `1` if all rows, columns and 3x3 grid does not contain the number and `0` otherwise.

If the problem is probably in one of the other functions, please let me know, I will send code. Ignore the `depth` variable.

Below is my code:

```
/* Returns an int which indicates whether if the sudoku has any
   more empty entries (which shows as a 0) */
int FindUnassignedLocation(int grid[9][9]) { 
    for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) 
        for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) 
            if (grid[row][col] == 0) 
                return 1; 
    return 0; 
}

/* Returns an int which indicates whether an assigned entry 
   in the specified row matches the given number. */
int UsedInRow(int grid[9][9], int row, int num) { 
    for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) 
        if (grid[row][col] == num) 
            return 1; 
    return 0; 
} 

/* Returns an int which indicates whether an assigned entry 
   in the specified column matches the given number. */
int UsedInCol(int grid[9][9], int col, int num) { 
    for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) 
        if (grid[row][col] == num) 
            return 1; 
    return 0; 
} 

/* Returns an int which indicates whether an assigned entry 
   within the specified 3x3 box matches the given number. */
int UsedInBox(int grid[9][9], int boxStartRow, int boxStartCol, int num) { 
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) 
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) 
            if (grid[row + boxStartRow][col + boxStartCol] == num) 
                return 1; 
    return 0; 
} 

/* Returns an int which indicates whether it will be legal to assign 
   num to the given row,col location. */
int isSafe(int grid[9][9], int row, int col, int num) { 
    /* Check if 'num' is not already placed in current row, 
       current column and current 3x3 box */
    if (!UsedInRow(grid, row, num) && 
        !UsedInCol(grid, col, num) && 
        !UsedInBox(grid, row - row % 3, col - col % 3, num) && 
        grid[row][col] == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
} 

void solve_sudoku(int sudoku[9][9]) {
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    if (FindUnassignedLocation(sudoku) == 0) { //if sudoku is completely filled
        return;
    }
    for (int num = 1; num <= 9; num++) {
        if (isSafe(sudoku, row, col, num) == 1) {
            sudoku[row][col] = num;
            solve_sudoku(sudoku, depth);
            sudoku[row][col] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: we do not see a lot with only that, indexes in `sudoku[i][j]` are correct, the problem is not visible in the shown code, give us more. Not link with your problem but add the type _int_ for _depth_ to be more clear. Perhaps you go out of the array when checking the 3x3 from a border ?

Comment: What kind of crash (access violation, stack overflow, etc)? What line is the crash on? Have you run it through a debugger and looked at things around the line that crashed?

Comment: What is `, depth` for? Should it be `, int depth`?

Comment: where is the original `grid` declared?

Comment: @bruno I added code for findunassignedlocation, isSafe, and its helper functions

Comment: @bruno it's a syntax error and cannot be ignored. It also hints that it isn't the true code.

Comment: I dont think that your code will work even when it doesn't crash.  You never reset the sudoku grid inside the while (findUnassignedLocation == 1) loop.  This means that you will get into an infinite loop.  You will get a partially filled in grid that has an impossible to fill cell.  Then you will try and change the existing numbers 1 by 1 which will generate the same numbers again with the same empty cell again.  This non-solution will never leave the outer loop.

Comment: I don't think the code crashes. It currently gets stuck in an infinite loop as Mike pointed out. And when that's fixed, the code could still take a very long time, depending on the puzzle.

Comment: @MikeWodarczyk I see the problem. I think solving it with loops is too complicated but do you know how I can solve it using recursion? I have some code here that I got inspiration from online but it does not seem to work. it is in the edits.

Comment: @Mingdi I edited my answer with a way to do

Answer (score 2):

A simple (but not the most efficient because of symmetries/rotations) way is to try all the possibilities trying to place the number 1 up to 9 on the successive positions (0,0 0,1 .. 0,8 1,0 ... ) recursively, each time a number can be put on 8,8 it is a solution

Few changes are needed from your code, just to remove the useless *FindUnassignedLocation* and add the recursion

If I replace 9 by SZ to also be able to search for the sizes 3, 6 or 9 and I add the draw of the solutions the code can be :

```
#include <stdio.h>

// 3, 6 or 9
#define SZ 9

/* Returns an int which indicates whether an assigned entry 
   in the specified row matches the given number. */
int UsedInRow(int grid[][SZ], int row, int num) 
{ 
  for (int col = 0; col < SZ; col++)
    if (grid[row][col] == num) 
      return 1; 

  return 0; 
} 

/* Returns an int which indicates whether an assigned entry 
   in the specified column matches the given number. */
int UsedInCol(int grid[][SZ], int col, int num) 
{ 
  for (int row = 0; row < SZ; row++) 
    if (grid[row][col] == num) 
      return 1; 

  return 0; 
} 

/* Returns an int which indicates whether an assigned entry 
   within the specified 3x3 box matches the given number. */
int UsedInBox(int grid[][SZ], int boxStartRow, int boxStartCol, int num) { 
  for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) 
    for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) 
      if (grid[row + boxStartRow][col + boxStartCol] == num) 
        return 1; 

  return 0; 
} 


/* Returns an int which indicates whether it will be legal to assign 
   num to the given row,col location. */
int isSafe(int grid[][SZ], int row, int col, int num) 
{ 
  /* Check if 'num' is not already placed in current row, 
     current column and current 3x3 box */
  return (!UsedInRow(grid, row, num) && 
          !UsedInCol(grid, col, num) && 
          !UsedInBox(grid, row - row % 3, col - col % 3, num));
} 

/* print a solution */
void draw(int sudoku[][SZ])
{
  for (int row = 0; row != SZ; ++row) {
    for (int col = 0; col != SZ; ++col)
      printf("%d", sudoku[row][col]);
    putchar('\n');
  }
  putchar('\n');
}

void solve_sudoku(int sudoku[][SZ], int row, int col)
{
  for (int num = 1; num <= 9; num++) { //loop through numbers 1 to SZ
    if (isSafe(sudoku, row, col, num) == 1) { //the number is safe
      sudoku[row][col] = num;
      if ((col + 1) == SZ) {
        if ((row + 1) == SZ) {
          // done
          draw(sudoku);
        }
        else
          solve_sudoku(sudoku, row + 1, 0);
      }
      else
        solve_sudoku(sudoku, row, col + 1);
      sudoku[row][col] = 0;
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  int sudoku[SZ][SZ] = {0};

  solve_sudoku(sudoku, 0, 0);
}
```

first solutions found for SZ 3 (362880 possible solutions) :

```
123
456
789

123
456
798

123
456
879

123
456
897

123
456
978

123
456
987

123
457
689
```

First solutions found for SZ 6 :

```
123456
456789
789123
214365
365897
897214

123456
456789
789123
214365
365897
897241

123456
456789
789123
214365
365897
978214

123456
456789
789123
214365
365897
978241

123456
456789
789123
214365
365978
897214

123456
456789
789123
214365
365978
897241
```

First solutions found for SZ 9

```
123456789
456789123
789123456
214365897
365897214
897214365
531642978
642978531
978531642

123456789
456789123
789123456
214365897
365897214
897214365
531642978
648971532
972538641

123456789
456789123
789123456
214365897
365897214
897214365
531642978
672938541
948571632

123456789
456789123
789123456
214365897
365897214
897214365
531642978
678931542
942578631

123456789
456789123
789123456
214365897
365897214
897214365
531642978
942578631
678931542
```

Comment: `!UsedInBox(grid, row - row%3 , col - col%3, num)` seems to indicate that the start will only be 0, 3, or 6