# Sudoku solver ( unable to get multiple solution)

Tags: c++

Currently having a problem with producing more than one solution, with my current function, I am only able to produce one solution. Is there any modification to my code that I can do to find out if the sudoku puzzle has more than one solution?

```
int Sudoku::solve(int sudokuboard[9][9]) {
    int row, col;

if(!Sudoku::taken(sudokuboard,row,col)) {
    return true;
}

for(int num =1;num <=9;++num) {
     if(Sudoku::legal(sudokuboard,row,col,num)) {
         sudokuboard[row][col]=num;
         if(Sudoku::solve(sudokuboard))
             return true;

         sudokuboard[row][col]=0;
     }
}
return false;
```

Comment: Can you format your code properly? Should just be highlight your code and press `{}`

Comment: Your code don't care of the position (it is unchanged), you cannot do that. I put a solution in an answer

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any modification to my code that i can do to find out if the sudoku puzzle has more than one solution ?

Your code don't care of the position letting *row,col* unchanged, you cannot do that.

You need to try all the possibilities, placing the number 1 up to 9 on the successive positions (0,0 0,1 .. 0,8 1,0 ... ) recursively, each time a number can be put on 8,8 it is a solution

A simple (but not the most efficient because of symmetries/rotations) way is, putting the grid as a member of the class else I don't really understand the interest to have a class rather than just C functions :

```
#include <iostream>

#define SZ 9

class Sudoku {
  public:
    void solve() { solve(0, 0); }
  private:
    void solve(int row, int col);
    bool UsedInRow(int row, int num) const;
    bool UsedInCol(int col, int num) const;
    bool UsedInBox(int boxStartRow, int boxStartCol, int num) const;
    bool isSafe(int row, int col, int num) const;
    void draw() const;

    int grid[SZ][SZ] = {0};
};


/* Returns an int which indicates whether an assigned entry 
   in the specified row matches the given number. */
bool Sudoku::UsedInRow(int row, int num) const { 
  for (int col = 0; col < SZ; col++)
    if (grid[row][col] == num) 
      return true; 

  return false; 
} 

/* Returns an int which indicates whether an assigned entry 
   in the specified column matches the given number. */
bool Sudoku::UsedInCol(int col, int num) const { 
  for (int row = 0; row < SZ; row++) 
    if (grid[row][col] == num) 
      return true; 

  return false; 
} 

/* Returns an int which indicates whether an assigned entry 
   within the specified 3x3 box matches the given number. */
bool Sudoku::UsedInBox(int boxStartRow, int boxStartCol, int num)  const { 
  for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) 
    for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) 
      if (grid[row + boxStartRow][col + boxStartCol] == num) 
        return true; 

  return false; 
} 


/* Returns an int which indicates whether it will be legal to assign 
   num to the given row,col location. */
bool Sudoku::isSafe(int row, int col, int num) const { 
  /* Check if 'num' is not already placed in current row, 
     current column and current 3x3 box */
  return (!UsedInRow(row, num) && 
          !UsedInCol(col, num) && 
          !UsedInBox(row - row % 3, col - col % 3, num));
} 

/* print a solution */
void Sudoku::draw() const {
  for (int row = 0; row != SZ; ++row) {
    for (int col = 0; col != SZ; ++col)
      std::cout << grid[row][col];
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

void Sudoku::solve(int row, int col) {
  for (int num = 1; num <= 9; num++) { //loop through numbers 1 to SZ
    if (isSafe(row, col, num) == 1) { //the number is safe
      grid[row][col] = num;
      if ((col + 1) == SZ) {
        if ((row + 1) == SZ) {
          // done
          draw();
        }
        else
          solve(row + 1, 0);
      }
      else
        solve(row, col + 1);
      grid[row][col] = 0;
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  Sudoku s;

  s.solve();
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra -Wall s.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out|more
123456789
456789123
789123456
214365897
365897214
897214365
531642978
642978531
978531642

123456789
456789123
789123456
214365897
365897214
897214365
531642978
648971532
972538641

123456789
456789123
789123456
214365897
365897214
897214365
531642978
672938541
948571632

123456789
456789123
789123456
214365897
365897214
897214365
531642978
678931542
--More--
```

Note : this is a derivation of the solution I given for C in [Sudoku solver in c crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55404166/sudoku-solver-in-c-crashes)

Answer (score 0):

Taking aside the suboptimal performance and design issues, the code is almost enough to get multiple solutions.

What you need is a relatively minor change:

```
if(Sudoku::solve(sudokuboard)) 
     print(sudokuboard);
// no return.
// continue to the next possibility, as if the last selection failed.
sudokuboard[row][col]=0;
```

The `print` can be replaced with `save`, or any other kind of method to handle the solution. Better, pass the handling operation through an object, such as a reference to `std::function`. This will allow a flexibility to decide on the action at runtime, without duplicating or modifying any code.